# How to split the display vertically when 2 horizontal windows exist

Tags: emacs

Could anyone please give me a hand to split the display vertically to create a third window that spans across the entire frame when there are two pre-existing windows side by side?

I often have an open window, then I do an org-capture to create a todo, but then I'm not sure about the date, so I open the calendar which gets scrunched underneath Window # 1 -- I'd like the calendar to span the length of the frame.

Example:

```
Window # 1    |     org-capture window
```

Then, split screen vertically:

```
Window # 1    |     org-capture window
______________________________
           calendar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon examining `calendar.el`, I saw that much work had been done by the developer(s) to select the window location / size.  Rather than using `defalias` and modifying the functions in `calendar.el` and/or `org-capture.el`, the following is a simple method to display the calendar across the entire bottom of the frame when using org-capture.

**EDIT**:  Replaced `(windmove-left)` and `(windmove-right)` with `(other-window 1)`, which is needed when using the `lawlist-org-capture` function on smaller resolution screens.  `org-capture` splits the screen vertically instead of horizontally when the user has a lower resolution display, and visa-versa on a higher resolution display.  `(other-window 1)` works for both situations.

```
(defun lawlist-org-capture ()
  (interactive)
  (org-capture)
  (setq lawlist-org-restore-a (buffer-name))
  (other-window 1)
  (setq lawlist-org-restore-b (buffer-name))
  (delete-other-windows)
  (calendar)
  (windmove-up)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (switch-to-buffer lawlist-org-restore-b)
  (other-window 1)
  (switch-to-buffer lawlist-org-restore-a) )
```